# Does the size of the code have any impact on the compile or runtime?

Tags: compilation, runtime

For example, in many programming languages there are two ways to execute a loop. I'm referring to, of course, for loops and while loops. Would these two examples have any differences in compile time or runtime? Does it depend on the programming language?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i+=0){
//Infinite loop
}
while(true){
//Infinite loop
}
```

FORTRAN 90 uses two different syntax for a loop

```
DO
    IF(CONDITION) EXIT
END DO
DO WHILE(CONDITION)
END DO
```

The first one has more characters, but I'm unsure if more characters means more compile/run time (as insignificant as that time would be).

Answer (score 1):

"More characters"  really, really isn't the problem.

Compilers and interpreters have t deal with e.g. symbol tables. And the `for` loop has an extra symbol. That will matter far more. Also, there are two operators, and you need to consider the types of arguments there, all of which add up.

Decent compilers will turn either loop into a no-op though.